# Test if a string matches with any RegExp element of an array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to develop a modular function that check if a `string` matches with a slice of RegExp.
As a matter of context:

```js
// Object containing regular expressions
const regex = {
    uppercase: /(?=.*[A-Z])/,  // Find Capital letters
    digits: /(?=.*\d)/,        // Find Digits
};

// Text to be compared
const text = "Hello World";  // It contains Capital and lowercase letters

// Call to function
console.log(contains(text, regex.uppercase, regex.digits));  // Expected output: `true` because the 'H' and 'W'
```

The problem is when I compare the RegExp's slice using `forEach()`, as this:

```js
function contains(str, ...pattern) {  // Receive the Text to be compared and a slice with RegExp
    pattern.forEach((regex) => {  // Loop for each RegExp in pattern slice
        if (regex.test(str)) {  // Check if a RegExp is in `str`
            return true;  // `true` if any RegExp matches
        }
    });

    return false;  // Return `false` if no one Expression is in the string
}
```

In this case I compared if is any Capital letter or digit in the string, but this code always returns `false`. And I don't know what I'm doing bad. Instead, this code using `for of` works:

```js
function contains(str, ...pattern) {  // Receive the Text to be compared and a slice with RegExp
    for (const regex of pattern) {  // Loop for each RegExp in pattern slice
        if (regex.test(str)) {  // Check if a RegExp is in `str`
            return true;  // `true` if any RegExp matches
        }
    }

    return false;  // Return `false` if no one Expression is in the string
}
```

When I compare in `contains()` ussing the `forEach()` loop, it always returns `false` as it doesn't match with the RegExp. But the `for of` loop works perfectly.

Even though it seems to me that they do the same thing.

Why the first method doesn't works?

Comment: Why not use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?  Also the [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method doesn't work because `forEach` does not act on returned contents.

Comment: If you just want to use `.test()`, then there's no need to use lookahead: `[A-Z]`/`\d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method doesn't work because you pass the code to execute on each element as a callback function and `forEach` does not care about its return value. `return` only returns from the nearest enclosing function and in your case, it returns from the `forEach` callback function. The return value is ignored by `forEach` and the outer function (`contains`) is not affected at all.

It should be noted that the appropriate array method to use here is [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which checks if the callback function provided returns a truthy value for any element in the array.

```js
function contains(str, ...pattern) {
  return pattern.some(p => p.test(str));
}
const regex = {
    uppercase: /(?=.*[A-Z])/,
    digits: /(?=.*\d)/,
};
const text = "Hello World";
console.log(contains(text, regex.uppercase, regex.digits));
```

Answer (score 0):

why make the code so complicated when the library is already provided in the browser. the function of `forEach` is to change the value of the caller. and does not return any value. as an example. i suggest to use `.map` instead of `.forEach`

```js
// Text to be compared
const text = "Hello World-12a"; 
// find `UpperCase` and `digit`
// /[A-Z]/g -> find UpperCase
// /[*\d]/g or /[0-9]/g -> find digit
var test = text.match(/[A-Z\(*\d)]/g)
console.log(test) // ['H','W','1','2']
let contains = (function(){
    return text
    .match(/[A-Z\(*\d)]/g)
    .map(e => text.includes(e)).length != 0
})();
console.log(contains) // true
```